# Matched String is not going to Pass statement in the if else condition java

Tags: java, if-statement, flat-file

I am trying to validate fixed length file count with the database count where when it match the counts then pass statement is not executing in the if statement however, it is going to else statement. Any direction will be apprpriciated.

Following is my code:

```
static String ubservicesCount = "";

    String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://"+strpServer+":"+strpPort+";databaseName="+strpDatabase+";IntegratedSecurity=true";

                // Declare the JDBC objects.  
                Connection con = null;  
                Statement stmt = null;  
                ResultSet rs = null;  

                Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");  
                con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl); 

                String SQL = strpQuery5+Qt+ProcessID+Qt;
                stmt = con.createStatement();  
                rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);  

                while (rs.next()) {
                    ubservicesCount = rs.getString(1);
                    System.out.println("UB servicesCount is " +ubservicesCount);
                }

                String st;
                BufferedReader Br = null;
                File objFile = new File(strPlanFile+NewFileNmae);
                Br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(objFile));

                List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                while ((st = Br.readLine()) != null) {

                    String arraylist = st;              

                    String RcdType = arraylist.substring(0, arraylist.length()-392);

                    list.add(RcdType);          

                }

                Set<String> unique = new HashSet<String>(list);
                for (String key : unique) {


                    if(key.trim().toString().equals("SALINE")){

                        System.out.println(key + ": " + Collections.frequency(list, key));

                        int fileCount = Collections.frequency(list, key);

                        if(ubservicesCount.trim().toString().equals(fileCount))

                            objReport.setValidationMessageInReport("PASS", "Flat File "+key+" count "+fileCount+" is Matched with Database ubdiagcodes Count "+ubservicesCount);                                                                  
                        else
                        {
                            objReport.setValidationMessageInReport("FAIL", "Flat File "+key+" count "+fileCount+" is not Matched with Database ubdiagcodes Count "+ubservicesCount);                

                        }                       
                    }                               
                }

                Br.close();
```

After the execution it print failed in the else statement in my report. I debugged where I can see that in the compare statement it is matching the counts. I am not sure what I am missing here.

Comment: Maybe the problem is that you're checking to see if a string value is equal to an integer value?   What if you compare them both as strings or both as integers?

Comment: @TabAlleman - for me "compare them both as strings" worked. Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

`if(ubservicesCount.trim().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(String.ValueOf(fileCount)))`

I think the problem is that you are using .equals and comparing a String Object to an int...

i.e.

boolean java.lang.String.equals(Object anObject)

> Compares this string to the specified object. The result is true if
>   and only if the argument is not null and is a String object that
>   represents the same sequence of characters as this object.

Comment: What's the point of the `toString` when `trim` already produces a string? And since it's a number (which cannot have letters in its string representation in base 10), `equalsIgnoreCase` is unnecessary and `equals` sufficient.